# Перевод перемeнной в строку, Си

Tags: c

Что значит

> перевод переменной типа `long` в символьную строку в двоичном представлении?

Как понять? Можно пример? (Не обязательно код.)

**Обновление**

Почему такой код не подойдет?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int mas[100];
    int i=0;
    long a;
    int b=0;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    while(a>0)
    {
        mas[i]=a%2;
        a=a/2;
        i++;
    }

    i--;
    while(i>=0){
        printf("%d",mas[i] );
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: в long лежит число. а нужна строка из символов '1' и '0', обычно решается делением числа на 2 и записью остатков от деления в строку

Comment: `long i = 13; char i_binary = "11001";`

Comment: @Mike чем отличается от обычного перевода в двоичную систему?тем что в строку записывается?

Comment: Ну это и есть обычный перевод в двичную, я думаю они просто решили так витиевато вы...разится

Comment: @andy.37 что-то не то. Должно быть "1101" и тип `char[]` (ну или `const char*`) для 13.

Comment: @alexolut, ОМГ, Вы правы, конечно. Сразу два ляпа.

Comment: @andy.37 можно объяснить почему char[ ]??для 13

Comment: Замените `mas[i] = a % 2;` на `mas[i] = (a % 2) + '0';`,  "переверните" массив, добавьте в конец двоичный 0 и подойдет. Вообще-то максимальный размер массива можно вычислить `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT + 1` (значение CHAR\_BIT определено в limits.h) (Зачем (и как)  переворачивать понятно?)

Comment: @avp так он уже перевернут разве нет?в конце перед while и после

Comment: В печатном виде будет перевернут (это точно). Ну, а если завтра надо будет что-то делать с этой строкой кроме печати? Или печатать так: `printf("binary: %s\n", mas);`? Так лучше уж сразу. Кстати, если понадобится вывод в любую разумную систему счисления, то [можете ознакомится](http://pastebin.com/zaNt0Y8C)

Comment: @avp не очень понял почему прибавляем '0'...тем более фигню какую-то выдает

Comment: @dfd, для "1101", конечно. alex тоже ошибся)))

Comment: @andy.37 вот я тож об этом подумал)

Comment: Добавлять '0' надо для того, чтобы в строке (от Вас же *символьную строку требуют*) были данные в нормальной кодировке ([таблицу кодов ascii](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA) посмотрите). А выводить у Вас потом надо либо `putchar(mas[i]);`, либо `printf("%c", mas[i]);` (видите, `%c`, а не `%d`)

Comment: @dfd В вопросе написано, что нужно преобразовать long в **символьную** строку. Приведенный код выводит в стандартный поток перекодированные символы. Если такое отступление от условия задачи устраивает, то этот код должен работать. В противном случае - рекомендации avp нужно учесть.

Comment: Тип для строки, а 13 это входное значение, которое дает "1101" на выходе.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Имеется в виду строка, в которой в человекочитаемом виде лежит двочная запись указанного числа. Например:

```
long l = 100;
const char b[] = "1100100";
```

Для перевода в бинарное представление чисел типа `long` можно воспользоваться нестандартной, но поддерживаемой большинством компиляторов функцией `ltoa`. Вот простейшая программа, иллюстрирующая её использование:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int l = 100;
    char b[sizeof(int) * 8 + 1];
    ltoa(l, b, 2);
    printf("%s\n", b);
}
```

Comment: ниже код подходит?

Answer (score 0):

Реализация может быть например такая.

```
#include <limits.h>
void ltoa(long l, char s[static sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT+1]) {
    unsigned long msk = 1UL << (sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT -1);
    while (msk != 0) {
        *s++ = (l & msk) ? '1' : '0';
        msk >>= 1;
    }
    *s = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Только лидирующих нулей может быть много... (а может они нужны ТС?)

Comment: Ну, я исходил из того, что в двоичном виде часто хочется видеть все разряды. Но это уже кому что нужно.

Comment: В gcc (и говорят clang) для определения количества ведущих нулей [можно использовать](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins)  `int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)`, `int __builtin_clzl (unsigned long)` и `int __builtin_clzll (unsigned long long)`